# DNS- implement domain Alias AND reconfigure Credentials

Tags: dns, alias, credentials

I am looking at using an existing external domain (say, for example, https://external.host1.com/resources/) as an alias within an internal wifi network. For example, the previously-mentioned public resource url would serve as an alias for  https://internal.host2.com/resources/.

In this example, the result would be when user is on the given wifi network and GETS resource at

https://external.host1.com/resources/resource.csv, they instead download from https://internal.host2.com/resources/resource.csv

From what I have seen, this is feasible through DNS configuration. What I want to know is DNS can also reconfigure the credentials or certificates. For example, if a client within the wifi network is designed to obtain OAuth token for the resource in https://external.host1.com/resources/, can DNS reroute this in such a way to obtain token (or other credential) for https://internal.host2.com/resources/?

UPDATE: The previous version of this post used Azure Blob and Sharepoint URLs as an example. I edited the URs to make it more generic, as the aliasing probably will not involve either one of those.

Comment: Your question does not make sense when mapped to reality. You are confounding different concepts handled differently between parts of the IP stack. Your solution requires an understanding of DNS (which here means domain to IP mapping), http(s) which relates to recognising web resources - and is not part of DNS, and then https and application level controls.

Answer (score 1):

1. What you describe is *NOT* just a DNS change. You are talking about mapping one URL to another

- https://public.blob.core.windows.net/resources/resource.csv
- https://internal.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/internal/resources/resource.csv

where the path on those URLs -- the part after the hostname -- is NOT the same. DNS could only change the hostname part, leaving the path untouched, since that's part of the HTTP protocol and not part of DNS.

Given that your destination path appears to be SharePoint, which runs on IIS, the most straightforward way to do the path mapping is to use a [URLRewrite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module) rule.

2. Neither the DNS system nor the IIS web server hosting sharepoint will "convert certificates" for you. What you can do instead is to obtain a certificate for `public.blob.core.windows.net`, and use it to set up a second https binding on the same IIS site as `internal.sharepoint.com`, with the hostname `public.blob.core.windows.net`.
3. If you are unable to obtain this secondary certificate and configure Sharepoint to use it and also add a URLRewrite to handle the differing paths, then your next move is to install some sort of proxy server between the Internet and your internal Sharepoint server.

---

This is my go-to analogy for the differences:

DNS is like 411 (directory assistance for phones).
IIS is a receptionist.
URLrewrite changes what the receptionist hears.

You ask directory assistance for rpresser's phone number. It replies 555-555-1212.

> Your browser asks DNS for www.hostname.com's IP address. It replies 10.4.0.1

The receptionist answers the phone and asks who you want. You answer "rpresser"

> Your browser connects to IIS at 10.4.0.1, sends `Host: www.hostname.com` and `GET /resources` and `Authorization: xdlsjflsjdf`

The receptionist is hard of hearing so someone else listens to "rpresser" and yells in her ear **RPRESSER**

> URLRewrite removes the `Authorization` header and changes `GET /resources` to `GET /deep/resources`

The receptionist rings through to my number and connects the call. I start talking.

> IIS looks up /deep/resources on the [www.hostname.com](http://www.hostname.com) site and returns whatever's there.

Comment: Thank you, Ross. To clarify, I used the Azure Blob and SharePoint URLs for the sake of the example, but this configuration probably will not touch on those domains. That said, you mention that that this will only change the hostname- would it be correct that this would convert https://external.host1.com/resources/ to https://internal.host2.com/resources/? Additionally, if I want to simply *remove* the authorization header from the request to external.host1 when rerouting to internal.host2, is DNS capable of doing this, or do I need some sort of service in-between?

Comment: "only change the hostname": Yes, you understand that part correctly; /resources remains /resources.

Comment: "remove the authorization header": DNS will not do ANYTHING to the HTTP request. The headers and payload will be delivered to whatever webserver matches DNS. It is up to the webserver to decide what to do with it once it gets there.  Notably, removing an incoming request header is quite readily accomplished with [URLRewrite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module).